# Include value of variable in destroy data confirm message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

What I would like to do is when I delete an article I want to have a pop up message say "Are you sure you want to delete **(name of article here)**?"

Here's what I have so far.

````
<% @articles.each do |article| %>
        <tr>
            <td><%= article.title %></td>
            <% @current_title = article.title %>
            <td><%= article.text %></td>
            <td><%= link_to 'Show', article_path(article), id: "submit" %></td>
            <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_article_path(article), id: "submit" %></td>
            <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', article_path(article), id: "submit",
                    method: :delete, onclick:"articleConfirm(current_title)",
                    data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }%></td>
            <td><a href=#top id="submit">Top</a></td>
        </tr>
<% end %>```
````

What this does is show the article title, content of the article as well as certain options (edit, show, delete or scroll to top).

I have printed out the value of @current_title and it does show the current title of the row that you look in the index page. Ideally, I would like to include @current_title in the confirm message if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a Javascript `alert` box when user wants to delete a message, Here you don't have to include `onclick:"articleConfirm(@current_title)"`, just do this:

```
<td><%= link_to 'Destroy', article_path(article), id: "submit",
        method: :delete,
        data: { confirm: "Are you sure you want to delete #{ @current_title } Article?" }%></td>
```

---

Now, if you want some modal, I'll show a an example of Bootstrap modal, then do this:

```
<td>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger" 
          data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal<%= article.id %>">Delete
  </button>
</td>
```

Then write your modal code and in that model you can do something like this:

```
<!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal<%= article.id %>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body">
          Are you sure you want to delete <%= article.title %>?
        </div>

        <!-- Delete button in the footer -->
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
          <%= link_to 'Delete', article_path(article), id: "submit", method: :delete, class: 'btn btn-outline-danger' %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

As you see, `#exampleModal<%= article.id %>` is added to fireup exact article modal.

Comment: I think I will go with the simpler method for now. The modal example looked cool, I was going for something easier to setup. I swear I think I was using the {} incorrectly. Thank you so much!

Comment: Yes you can go with the simpler method, but if you want to `alert` to be more intuitive, you can check out Sweetalerts2 lib - https://sweetalert2.github.io/ , This library will style the default JS `alert` and `popup` boxes. You can google it on how to use with Rails, or if you have DriftingRuby subscription check this out - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fFZEmpMpZL0